# automate "yes" for new host when SSH

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I am trying to automate SSH into a new IP. I get this message

```
The authenticity of host '12.82.147.35 (88.88.999.88)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is b6:b3:06:e1:31:2b:f8:32:a5:c0:ae:dc:46:6d:b7:39.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

How do I automatically answer `yes`

to this question?

Comment: You could prepare the known_hosts file in advance. If you don't know the hosts in advance, then you should not automate. Security hole.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'man ssh-keyscan' - it is a tool for building a known hosts file - from the man page:

> **ssh-keyscan** uses non-blocking socket I/O to contact as many hosts as
>   possible in parallel, so it is very efficient.  The keys from a domain
>   of 1,000 hosts can be collected in tens of seconds, even when some of
>   those hosts are down or do not run ssh.  For scanning, one does not
>   need login access to the machines that are being scanned, nor does the
>   scanning process involve any encryption.

Note that you still have to authenticate and/or establish your key relationship for key based logins.